# WSO2 EI - how to handle malformed JSON requests in API

Tags: api, request, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I have created an API in WSO2 EI.
API is expecting the requests to be send as JSON.
If it is a malformed JSON which is sent, then I should be able to receive it and make appropriate changes to make it a proper JSON.

Any help is much appreciated.

As we are using json-eval($.) to get the message to property, it is not working for me. What else i could try instead of json-eval to get the message as string.

Answer (score 3):

WSO2 EI has the property **force.json.message.validation**, which can be used to validate incoming JSON payload. Please refer [doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Working+with+Message+Builders+and+Formatters#WorkingwithMessageBuildersandFormatters-ValidatingJSONmessages) to configure this property in 'passthru-http.properties' file.

Once the property is configured, if there is a malformed JSON payload in the request, the mediation flow will be directed to the fault/error sequence. So, you can define the mediation logic to make appropriate changes to the malformed content within the fault sequence of your API.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response!

I am not seeing the feature set by default. Any idea what is the default value for it ?

Comment: Even i tried applying the setting. But still not working :(

Also, FYI, I am using 6.4.0 version.

Comment: This feature is not enabled by default. To enable the feature, you have to add 'force.json.message.validation=true' inside EI-HOME/conf/passthru-http.properties file and restart the server. Then, test it with a malformed JSON content.

Comment: I've put force.json.message.validation=false as I dont need validation. Is this correct ?

Comment: You need to put 'force.json.message.validation=true' as you need the validation to identify a malformed json request.

Comment: my requirement is to receive the JSON and make appropriate changes to make it a proper JSON